# C++ OpenGL Program - Add Icon

Tags: c++, opengl, icons, glfw

I would like to add an icon to my C++ OpenGL program.

My IDE is: Notepad++ and a command prompt window. I am not using the Win32 API, I am instead using the GLFW3 window manager.

Please can anyone tell me how to add an icon **without** Visual Studio, Dev-C++ or any other IDE, or through a 3rd party app such as Resource Hacker.

Answer (score 3):

Add a resource definition to your program, definiting a application icon `APP_ICON`. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx

Comment: I think this is the solution I have been looking for. Could you point me to a tutorial that goes over this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add or change the icon of your program after compilation, thereby changing the icon of an actual .exe file. Then you can use [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/), *be aware that there is only a version for Windows.*

- ResEdit - http://www.resedit.net/

How to add change icon with ResEdit

1. Open ResEdit.exe
2. Click on File -> Open Project ... and select your .exe file
3. Right click in the Resource panel ... Add Resource ... Icon ... and then load the image you want to have as an icon.
4. Remember to save, and then you're done!

Comment: Actually, and I suppose I wasn't that clear on this, but I want to do this with JUST code... So no 3rd party applications.

Comment: Sorry, though you only meant without an IDE :)